# A lemma of Kakutani’s theorem: prove that Any correspondence having a convex graph is also convex valued.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, self-learning, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

How can prove the following sentence?

> a correspondence having a convex graph is convex valued as well.

In order to explain the functions which used in this proof context,

This comes from Kakutani’s theorem:

Let$ f : S \to S $ be a correspondence. If S is nonempty, compact, and convex, and if f is nonempty-valued, convex-valued, and has a closed graph, then f has a fixed point.
When we say that f is nonempty-valued and convex-valued, we mean that $f(s) $ is a nonempty convex set for every $s \in S$.

Please look at[the lecture note, page 3](http://www.u.arizona.edu/%7Emwalker/02_Equilibrium%20Existence/Correspondences.pdf)

Also please look at [the book, page 229](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=yAfug81P-8YC&pg=PA229&lpg=PA229&dq=correspondence%20having%20a%20convex%20graph%20is%20in%20a%20convex%20set&source=bl&ots=_KWJaa03RG&sig=ACfU3U2UQ0BuDmHD33CMV-299WBkUNrySA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi27IaXgNX5AhUUVfEDHd8sDTUQ6AF6BAgsEAM#v=onepage&q=correspondence%20having%20a%20convex%20graph%20is%20in%20a%20convex%20set&f=false) “
Every correspondence with convex graph is also convex valued, but the converse is false.

I want to prove this first part.  Please share your ideas with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f: X\to\!\!\!\to Y$ be a correspondence with convex graph.

Let $x\in X$ and $y_1, y_2\in f(x)$, i.e., $(x, f(y_1)), (x, f(y_2))\in \text{Gr}f$.
Let $\lambda\in (0,1)$.

Since $(x, f(y_1)), (x, f(y_2))\in \text{Gr}(f)$ and $f$ has convex graph, $$\lambda(x, f(y_1)) + (1-\lambda)(x, f(y_2))\in \text{Gr}(f).$$
Let us check the LHS.
$$\begin{aligned}
\lambda(x, f(y_1)) + (1-\lambda)(x, f(y_2))
&=(\lambda x, \lambda f(y_1)) +((1-\lambda)x, (1-\lambda)f(y_2))\\
&=(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)x,\, \lambda f(y_1) + (1-\lambda) f(y_2))\\
&=(x,\, \lambda f(y_1) + (1-\lambda) f(y_2)).
\end{aligned}$$
So, $(x, \lambda f(y_1) + (1-\lambda) f(y_2))\in\text{Gr(f)}$.
That means $\lambda f(y_1) + (1-\lambda) f(y_2)\in f(x)$.

Hence, $f(x)$ is convex-valued. $\quad\checkmark$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear proof.